# How to keep running an application in background in Android Wear(Galaxy watch 4) using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, background-service

I am collecting raw sensor data (HeartRate, accelerometer, gyroscope, etc.) with Samsung Watch 4. I need to run my data collection application continuously in the background. However, it seems the watch OS kills the application after some time.

So my question is -  **How can I keep my application running in the background continuously without being interrupted/killed by the watch OS?**

Comment: I'm not sure about android wear... Try workmanager this also minimum 15mins once can execute

Comment: You will likely have to tell the user to allow your app to run in the background. On older versions this is done via opening galaxy wear on the paired phone, going to settings -> apps -> your app -> allow background. However this is not the case in newer versions, instead of going to apps, go to battery settings -> your app -> allow background activity. Though you should really question if constant collection is really required.

Comment: @undermark5 There is no such option to allow background activity in the settings and I want to collect data for like 24 hours or more so constant collection is required.

Comment: @Pranay: did you get this done? Do you have this code available for sharing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Health Services https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services is the way to handle this for heartrate, so you don't need your app to always be running.

But if you need accelerometer and gyro specifically you will need to collect yourself, then you will have to run a Foreground Service.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

But if you just want accelerometer and gyro for movement to detect an activity, then WHS can do this for you.

See some of the samples here https://github.com/android/health-samples

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem when using gravity sensor. We tried to keep the screen on to solve it but it's not a ideal way because it will make the power down quickly.
Here is the code we used(Java):
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

Comment: If you have better solution, plz let me know! Thank u :)